# TypeError: can only concatenate str

Tags: python

I am making a Garfield video downloader. I ran into this error and don't know how to fix it.

```
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Jake/Desktop/garfield copy 2.py", line 10, in <module>
    url = 'http://pt.jikos.cz/garfield/' + year + '/' + month
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Code:

```
# Downloads Garfield Comic

import requests, os, bs4, threading
print('\t\t---------Garfield Comic Download---------')
t = 1
print('Enter the Year:')
year = input()
month = 1
while t < 12:
        url = 'http://pt.jikos.cz/garfield/' + year + '/' + month
        location = 'Garfield(' + month + '-' + year + ')'
        os.makedirs(location, exist_ok=True)

        def downloadGarfield(comicElem, startNum, endNum):
                # Download the images
                for i in range(startNum, endNum):
                        comicUrl = comicElem[i].get('src')
                        # Download the image.
                        print('Downloading the image %s...' % (comicUrl))
                        res = requests.get(comicUrl)
                        res.raise_for_status()

                        # Save the image to ./Garfield(month-year).
                        imageFile = open(os.path.join(location, os.path.basename(comicUrl)), 'wb')
                        for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
                                imageFile.write(chunk)
                        imageFile.close()

        # Download the page.
        print('Downloading page %s...' % url)
        res = requests.get(url)
        res.raise_for_status()

        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')

        # Find the URL of the comic image.
        comicElem = soup.select('table img')

        downloadThreads = []
        for i in range(0, len(comicElem), 2):
                downloadThread = threading.Thread(target = downloadGarfield, args=(comicElem, i, min(len(comicElem), i+2)))
                downloadThreads.append(downloadThread)
                downloadThread.start()

        # Wait for all threads to end.
        for downloadThread in downloadThreads:
                downloadThread.join()
        month + 1
        t + 1
        print('Done')
```

Comment: The error is quite self-explanatory. You have to convert ```year``` and ```month``` to strings using ```str(month),str(year)```

Comment: Or f-strings: `url = f'http://pt.jikos.cz/garfield/{year}/{month}'`

Answer (score 3):

You can't concatenate an integer to a string, you need to cast it to a string first.

`str(month)`

Answer (score 0):

cast the `int` to `str` in order to concatenate it:

```
url = 'http://pt.jikos.cz/garfield/' + str(year) + '/' + str(month)
```

Comment: year is already a string, its taken as input from user

Answer (score 0):

You can do as @0TTT0 and @devReddit answered you if you need month as int.

On the other hand, you need to define the increment of the variables (thanks to @Jeppe to realise about that):

```py
month+=1
t+=1
```

In this case that you can define a "new" month as str (if it makes you easier):

```py
month_s=str(month)
```

In this case you can use your concatenate as you did. However, I recommend you do it as follow:

```py
url = f'http://pt.jikos.cz/garfield/{year}/{month_s}'
location = f'Garfield({month_s}-{year})'
```

Comment: You will see that they are incrementing month iteratively which is why they have set it as an int.  Admittedly I didn't really look further

Comment: My fault, I misread it. I just re-write my answer

Comment: @0TTT0 actually the increments are not effective.